# Copying text file to another text file line by line?

Tags: batch-file

### Part 1

I'm trying to read a text file and then copy into another text file line by line.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
@echo off

for /f %%A in (input.txt) DO (
    for /f %%B in (output.txt) DO (
        echo %%A > output.txt
    )
)
```

It runs, but only puts the last line from input.txt into output.txt, while I want each line written. Any thoughts?

### My Main Project

My main project is to take the following input:

```
input.txt
/fruits-and-veggies/oranges
/fruits-and-veggies/brussel-sprouts
/fruits-and-veggies/apples
/fruits-and-veggies/passion-fruit
/fruits-and-veggies/broccoli
```

And then analyze them for the tag `<h1>Fruit!</h1>` and then compile the links that do contain them in the following output:

```
/fruits-and-veggies/oranges
/fruits-and-veggies/apples
/fruits-and-veggies/passion-fruit
```

Take these to be subdirectories to the website http://www.example.com .

I know I'll need to use FINDSTR and a for loop, but I'm not sure how to go about the batch file actually going into the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to append >> instead of write >.  You're overwriting your file every time you write.

Comment: I'm still a little confused, I'm sorry, but I've switched it from ">" to ">>" and now it won't even run. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks, by the way, for answering.

Comment: No problem, mind posting what you had to do for future Googlers, and mark the question answered?

Comment: Sure... what should I do about a Part II to the question? I can only post every 20 minutes.

Comment: Spend the time helping out other people in need :)?  Spend the 20 minutes attempting to solve the issue?  If you'd like to I may be able to help out further, but there's a certain satisfaction to cracking a nut by yourself.

Comment: I've been looking through the questions trying to offer help, but it seems my knowledge is too rudimentary to answer any of these questions. As for cracking it myself, I'm just not familiar with batch and all of my researching attempts come up empty handed. I'll try to search for more people to help though!